# Surround sound in Windows 10 without extra hardware

Tags: windows-10, audio, desktop, speakers, surround-sound

Is there any way to get surround sound in Windows 10 without purchasing extra hardware?  I have several outputs on my motherboard along with an output on my monitor, but is there a way to output a set of speakers as front speakers and a set of speakers as back speakers?

Hardware:

Dell U2417H

MSI B460M PRO-VDH WIFI

Comment: Short answer is no, you need a sound card that supports surround sound.

Comment: aren't `set of speakers` extra hardware?

Comment: I meant extra hardware that I don’t already have

Answer (score 1):

Many motherboards come with 7.1 outputs already on the rear plate - orange/black/grey

[image]

Yours doesn't, it only has the old standard mic/line/speaker options - blue/green/pink

[image]

[image]

You will have to buy a USB sound card designed to support 5.1 or 7.1
You can get one for maybe $£€ 10 on eBay etc.

Comment: If you buy anything better than the most cheap & nasty thing eBay has to offer [they start at round 3 bucks;) then they're all about the same. This is technology that was perfected to mass-production 20 years ago & hasn't changed much since.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks!